# Can't delete contacts from SIM card

Tags: contacts, sim-card

So in an attempt to undo all the [wrong word here] apps do in mixing contacts somehow, I ended up deleting all contacts from the entire phone including the SIM card, to then try to put them back either one by one or from a backup.

Though, I can't delete all contacts from the SIM card! Why is that??? Would anyone know? I could delete around 100 contacts, but I can't delete duplications of the contacts. I started blaming Whatsapp, Google account and another one which is MBWAY which is from a bank. They have contacts of their own or something. So I deleted all the accounts and uninstalled Whatsapp and MBWAY, tried again and no success... Now I installed an app called SIM Card Manager which I got from 4PDA, so I'm trusting it's an app that does the things right. And when I go on it to delete the contacts, it says "Cannot delete contact". Another app I got from Play Store allowed me to "delete", but when I restarted the app, it would show all the contacts I "deleted", so it didn't delete at all. The app from 4PDA at least says it can't. But if it can't and it actually knows it can't delete, I'm wondering VERY MUCH why...

Would anyone know why this happens and how I can delete the contacts?? Or I'll get an old phone which never got me any problems and delete the stuff from there... (if the phone will let me, since I can't here). I'm thinking those apps have to do with this. This never happened to me before. First time in my life I see I can't delete contacts. And I'm supposing it's from Whatsapp because one each contact that the person had Whatsapp, I had 2 duplicates of the original one on the SIM card. And I never asked Whatsapp to even try to do that, but why not......

Thanks in advance for any help on this...

Comment: Does your Phone have a system app to deal with SIM? If yes, enter into safe mode and try to delete

Comment: Yes, it does. And it seems it's crap, because it shows no numbers on the SIM and I know there are numbers... I know this because before, it wouldn't show copies of numbers and I knew there were numbers there because I have an app of mine reading all contacts and there were contacts there. So I got another app which showed the duplicates, since the official doesn't show... And now the app is saying there are contacts again, even though I can't see them from the official app, only from other apps. What safe mode are you talking about though? I only know of Safe Mode on Windows, not Android.

Comment: Oh wait, a system app to deal with the SIM card. What do you mean with that? I think I just confused an app to manage the card with the Contacts app hahaha. You mean a SIM manager? If that's it my bad, didn't get it the first time. It doesn't have any of those.

Comment: Oh, they I can't go there in any way hahaha. My dear phone has no screen nor touch glass XD. I control it with voice (an app of my own - which I might even publish), TeamViewer and the amazing Vysor. Interesting to know such thing exists though. Never heard of it. Some phones seem to have it on the Power menu, but mine doesn't. Maybe "too old" (Lollipop 5.1, OnePlus X). Can't go there anyways, so yeah xD. But thanks for the suggestion in any case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have waited a bit more. But maybe this helps someone else with the problem. I had just had to restart, load the app, see it still detected no contacts, leave the app, go on another app, wait a bit, and get back to Contacts app. Then it showed the problematic contacts. And I was able to delete them, only from the Contacts app.

And I think the problem is really from the apps that put duplicates --> Whatsapp, MBWAY, Google account, any other account on the system that synchronizes contacts. It creates duplicates and the phone got everything mixed up. Not sure if it's my fault or those apps' fault in mixing the contacts. I just wanted only the SIM contacts on the entire phone... But no.... The apps have to put the contacts of their own there. Cool. Thanks a lot. Amazing... But at least it's fixed. I deleted all the contacts and put them back one by one. Now I'll install the apps back and put my account and see what happens...